# Is there any method to find out which position my new number went to?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, push

I have my `array=[5,4,3,1]` below, I want to `.push(2)`, then `.sort()` my `array` and find out the new number's location in the array that I just pushed. I know the answer the new number's location is in `array[1]`.

```
var array = [5,4,3,1];
array.push(2); //My new number
var sortedArray = arr.sort();

// sortedArray [1,2,3,4,5]
// The new number's position went to array[1]
```

Is there any method to find out which position my new number went to?

Comment: Make an object array instead `[{ val:1,pos:1,orgpos:4},{val:2,pos:2,orgPos:null},....{val:4,pos4:orgPos:2},{val:5,pos:5,orgPos:1}]`

Comment: If the content of the array members is unique, `indexOf(2)` would do the trick. Basicly, `indexOf` would work even if there are duplicates, technically it's impossible to say, where exactly the newly added member is placed during the sorting.

Comment: What do you mean by *which array*?

Answer (score 1):

You could sort an array with indices and take the store index for serarching the inde fo the sorted array.

```js
var array = [5, 4, 3, 1],
    index = array.push(2) - 1,
    indices = array
        .map((_, i) => i)
        .sort((a, b) => array[a] - array[b]);

console.log(index);                  // old index
console.log(indices.indexOf(index)); // new index
console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```js
const array = [5, 4, 3, 1];
const n = 32;
array.push(n);

const sortedArray = array.sort();
const index = sortedArray.findIndex(el => el === n);
console.log(sortedArray, index)
```

Note that you sort could be improved if you're using numbers and you want them to be in ascending order after the sort:

```
const sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => b < a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` function.

- This approach returns an array of indexes of number `2` if this is repeated.
- In this case, will return an array with only one index.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
var array = [5,4,3,1];
array.push(2);

var indexes = array.sort().reduce((a, n, i) => {
  if (n === 2) {
    a.push(i);
  }
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(indexes));
```

See, returns an array with only one index.

## Resource

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)